# Caché SQL: Select string segments as separate columns?

Tags: sql, parsing, csv, intersystems-cache

Given [this documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20122/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL), how can I return the data below into individual columns in the results?

```
| id | text                         |
-------------------------------------
| 01 | apple,green,ford,steve       |
| 02 | orange,blue,chevy,paul       |
| 03 | banana,purple,nissan,james   |
```

I would like the results to look like this:

```
| fruit  | color  | car    | name  |
--------------------------------
| apple  | green  | ford   | steve |
| orange | blue   | chevy  | paul  |
| banana | purple | nissan | james |
```

I don't think variables are an option (no SET command in linked docs).  My end goal would be to do something like `SELECT DISTINCT car FROM (<parse statement here>)` so I could list all cars, or `SELECT name FROM (<parse statement here>) WHERE fruit = 'apple'` search for all names with a specific fruit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in Cache:

```
select * from (
    select $PIECE(text,',',1) fruit,
        $PIECE(text,',',2) color,
        $PIECE(text,',',3) car,
        $PIECE(text,',',4) name
    from mytable)
where fruit = 'apple';
```